# Streamlit Re-runs App on Button Click, Delaying Download

Tags: python-3.x, qr-code, streamlit

Problem:

I'm encountering an issue with my Streamlit app's download functionality. When I click the "Download QR Code" button, the app unexpectedly re-runs from the beginning, generating a duplicate button. The actual download only initiates upon clicking the second button.
this is my code

```
import streamlit as st
import qrcode
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image


def generate_qr_code(link):  # Generate QR Code
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1.00,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=2,
    )
    qr.add_data(link)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    return img


def download_qr_code(img):  # Convert PIL image to bytes
    img_bytes = BytesIO()
    img.save(img_bytes, format='PNG')
    img_bytes.seek(0)
    return img_bytes


st.title("QR Code Generator")
link = st.text_input("Enter a link:")

if link:
    qr_img = generate_qr_code(link)
    img = download_qr_code(qr_img)
    st.image(img, caption='Generated QR Code', width=300)

    if st.button('Download QR Code'):
        qr_bytes = download_qr_code(qr_img)
        st.download_button(label="Download QR Code", data=qr_bytes, file_name='qr_code.png', mime='image/png')
```

Troubleshooting Attempts:

I've also explored using st.session_state to store variables across re-runs, but I'm unsure of the correct implementation for this specific scenario.
in Here:

```
if "qr_bytes" not in st.session_state:
    if link:
        qr_img = generate_qr_code(link)
        qr_bytes = download_qr_code(qr_img)
        st.session_state.qr_bytes = qr_bytes
```

and

```
if st.button('Download QR Code'):
    if "qr_bytes" in st.session_state:
        data = st.session_state.qr_bytes
    else:
        # Fallback in case session data is missing
        qr_img = generate_qr_code(link)
        data = download_qr_code(qr_img)
        st.session_state.qr_bytes = data

    st.download_button(label="Download QR Code", data=data, file_name='qr_code.png', mime='image/png')
```

but it is not solved.
I want the download to initiate immediately upon clicking the first "Download QR Code" button, without any app re-runs or duplicate button generation.
I'm relatively new to Streamlit, so detailed explanations would be helpful.
I'm open to suggestions for alternative approaches if necessary.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!